# get user specific information from database after login

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, passwords

I am doing a project where I need to make a VLE system for a school website. I am using visual web developer 2008, C# and a SQL database. What I need to do is when a student logs in using their username and password they should have their specific information displayed from the database (like what course name, student ID, Email and name etc from the SQL) I have created the login page:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    con.Open();
    string cmdStr = "select count (*) from Registration where UserName ='" + TextBox1.Text + "'";
    SqlCommand checkuser = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, con);
    int temp = Convert.ToInt32(checkuser.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
    if (temp == 1)
    {
        String cmdStr2 = "select password from Registration where UserName ='" + TextBox1.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand pass = new SqlCommand(cmdStr2, con);
        String password = pass.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        con.Close();

        if (password == TextBox2.Text)
        {
            Session["New"] = TextBox1.Text;
            Response.Redirect("secure.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            Label1.Visible = true;
            Label1.Text = "Invalid Password....!!!";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Label1.Visible = true;
        Label1.Text = "Invalid UserName....!!!";
    }
}
```

Comment: It is considered "bad" to specifically report "invalid password" or "invalid user name". The reason is that it effectively lets a hostile know when they get a user name correct. When doing login functionality, there's a several sets of best practices to help developers avoid common problems, such as "don't store passwords in plain text". Doesn't take much searching to find these on the net.

Comment: Appending any old text into your database queries is bad for security (vulnerable to SQL Injection) and performance (can't re-use query plans). Anyone could destroy your database with your code how it is. The proper way to do this is parameterised queries - see [this](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#SQL_injection) for some good background on SQL Injection.

Comment: Use this for reference
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12907/Simple-Stored-Procedures-in-NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you get the user name then you can go for dataset to retrieve all the details about that user and show it in secure.aspx accordingly.

advice: dont use sql query directly(vulnerable to sql injections) , you should use stored proc..
and also dont store password in a plain text.
why are you retrieving data twice for same datas.

Comment: what i need to do is login into database and get the user information like his/her user name, Email, course details

Comment: yes i want get data in secure.aspx but how i will get i don't know maybe there is some query for login and get user info in secure page please give me the code if u know

Answer (score 0):

This won't solve all your problems, but I would read [this article](http://www.codehighstreet.com/Articles/overview_of_membership_and_installing_sql_membership_provider-part_1/overview_of_membership_and_installing_sql_membership_provider-part_1.aspx).

Your current Username and password solution isn't very secure at all as your currently storing the password as plain text.
This article explains how to install and setup a username and password database and use some controls that will handle the authentication for you

Comment: dear i can login web page using user name and password, i need to login page and get the user information after login from database not just name but also course details etc. maybe there are some login query to get user information from database but i don't know this code please help me